# WSO2 DTD for .dbs files

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am looking for the DTD of .dbs files, in WSO2 Dataservices.

I extracted all jars and searched for DTD files that could match with .dbs samples, but, at the end, it seems that no DTD files matched the criteria.

Do you know where if a DTD does exist for .dbs files, and, if so, where I can find it ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the schema associated with the DataService Description language via the following URL that that resides in the carbon public svn repository. [Data Service Schema](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/DataServices.xsd)